# Length is not worked in JSON Extractor in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter-3.2

I need to get the count of card from json file. For this I've used `$.storedCards.cards.lenght`
 in JSON Extractor but it doesn't work. There is an error message:

> Options AS_PATH_LIST and ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST are not allowed when using path functions!

After that I've tried JSR223 PostProcessor with next script on goovy

```
 def jsonText = '''${AllCards}''' //${AllCards} has json value
 def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonText)
 log.info( "Json length---------->"+json.resource.size())
 ${CardsCount} = props.get("4") //vars.put(json.resource.size.toString())
```

but there is problem with set value to my variable. Or when i've created variable in Groovy it was impossible to use outside from script.

My json file

```
    "storedCards":
    {
        "cards":
        [
            {
                "CardId":"123",
                "cardBrand":"Visa",
                "lastFourDigits":"2968",
               },
            {
                "CardId":"321",
                "cardBrand":"Visa",
                "lastFourDigits":"2968",
              },
     ..........
        ],
```

How can i get the count of card and set to my Variables? what should i use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data seems to be invalid. Assuming you have the valid JSON like below, I'm answering your question.

```
{
    "storedCards": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "CardId": "123",
                "cardBrand": "Visa",
                "lastFourDigits": "2968"
            },
            {
                "CardId": "321",
                "cardBrand": "Visa",
                "lastFourDigits": "2968"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You dont need to write Groovy code, you can resolve this using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor). Instead of using length function, use JSON path predicate like this-

```
$.storedCards.cards[*]
```

Though Variable you used in JSON Extractor won't give the solution right away, another JMeter function helps - **[__RandomFromMultipleVars](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars)**

Excerpt from documentation -

> The RandomFromMultipleVars function returns a random value based on the variable values provided by Source Variables.
>   The variables can be simple or multi-valued as they can be generated by the following extractors:
>
> ```
> Boundary Extractor
> Regular Expression Extractor
> CSS Selector Extractor
> JSON Extractor
> XPath Extractor
> XPath2 Extractor
> ```
>
> Multi-value vars are the ones that are extracted when you set -1 for
>   Match Numbers. This leads to creation of match number variable called
>   ***varName_matchNr*** and for each value to the creation of variable
>   varName_n where n = 1, 2, 3 etc.

So once you use the predicate, you will get the count in the ***yourVariableName_matchNr***. Example:-

[image]

[image]

Hope this help.